# Nesting questions in orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon

we are using Orbeon Forms version 2016.3 on project.
Currently we have to implement structure of questions as it is displayed in the following example on picture.
[image]

So those indented additional radio buttons should display only when second option from buttons in first line of indentation is selected. Otherwise, on any other selection they should dissapear.

We already know how to make logic for this behavior, but when it comes to appearence and nesting those radio buttons, we didn't manage to find some good solution then badly styling it in css (not looking nice when you are switching selection).

Is there any trick in Orbeon to nest those questions which should appear on specific selection?

Comment: Jovana, is this for a form you're creating with Form Builder, or are you writing XForms by hand? With Form Builder, I'm afraid it might be a bit convoluted, and will require you to add some [custom model logic](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom.html), but it should be doable. Just let me know if this indeed is the situation you're in, and I can try to prototype something for you.

Comment: Hi avernet, thanks for your reply. It would mean a lot to me if you could help me out with this. I am using Form Builder but it won't be a problem to add the necessary code directly to he XForm. Should I write a simple test case?

Comment: Got it Jovana, thank you for confirming you're using Form Builder. No need for a test case; I have a pretty good idea of what you'd like based on your description. I'll be out of of the office today, but will try to prototype something for you when I come back and will follow-up here.

Comment: Here we go Jovana: I've posted an answer with a prototype. The source of the form is from 2017.2, so if you want to try it as-is, you will have to wait a few days for the release to become publicly available. But you should be able to recreate a similar version with an earlier version, and might just need to add CSS to "indent" the nested radios. You'll let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot avernet for fast reply, we have tried it with our 2016.3 version and it works exactly how we wanted with a bit of additional styling. We would never figure this out by ourselves.

Comment: Excellent! I am glad this helped, and thank you for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate this, I've created a [prototype form](https://gist.github.com/avernet/b333195cf22c55bd846ecc266b14bb50) that you can run on Orbeon Forms 2017.2. The idea is pretty simple:

- The nested radios only show if the corresponding top radio is selected. This is done in Form Builder with a *Visibility* formula.
- If one top radios is checked, the others are reset. This is done in a [custom model](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom.html), as detailed below.

You reference to the custom model from your `properties-local.xml` with:

```
<property
    as="xs:anyURI"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.model.custom.*.*"
    value="oxf:/forms/resources/my-model.xml"/>
```

And add a `WEB-INF/resources/forms/resources/my-model.xml` with:

```
<xf:model xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <xf:action event="xforms-select" observer="top-1-control top-2-control">
        <xf:setvalue iterate="instance()/section-1/(top-1, top-2)" ref="."/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:model>
```